# ria extension vscode Elasticsearch: how to change hostname?

Tags: elasticsearch, visual-studio-code

I use the "ria" extension in VScode to connect to elastic search. Once I installed it, I set the host and everything is OK, but I can't change the host and I couldn't find any reference to guide me to help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it, Ctrl + Shift + P